# calculating area of intersecting geometries

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to set up an interpolation from blocks in 2000 to tracts in 2010. I would like to generate a column saying what percent of blocks are in each tract, so if block A were halfway in tract X and halfway in tract y, there would two observations for each pair, and the percent column would say 50%.

I am trying to follow [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362466/calculate-percentage-overlap-of-2-sets-of-polygons-in-r), but I get an error. I checked with st_is_valid and all the polygons are valid.

This is what I've tried:

```
library("sf")
library("tigris")
library("dplyr")

maricopa_blocks00 <- blocks(
      "AZ", 
      "Maricopa", 
      year = 2000
    )
    
    
maricopa_tracts10 <- tracts(
  "AZ", 
  "Maricopa", 
  year = 2010
)

intersect_pct <- st_intersection(maricopa_tracts10, maricopa_blocks00) %>%
  mutate(intersect_area = st_area(.))
```

Error is:

> Error in `stopifnot()`: ! Problem while computing `intersect_area = st_area(.)`. Caused by error in `wk_handle.wk_wkb()`: ! Loop 0 is not
> valid: Edge 106 is degenerate (duplicate vertex)

Comment: This isn't related to your code, but if all you need is a crosswalk between these two years of geographies, [NHGIS](https://www.nhgis.org/2000-block-data-standardized-2010-geography) might have one that works for you. Otherwise, do you think you can narrow down which tracts or blocks are throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just because two input geometries are valid, it doesn't mean their intersection is valid...

I tried doing this as you have, but tests with subsets of the second layer show it will take ages to do on my computer. This is because `sf` is doing spherical geometry calculations which are slow, and stop it using spatial indexes. If I switch spherical geometry off the computation is quicker and doesn't result in any validity errors:

```
> sf_use_s2(FALSE)
Spherical geometry (s2) switched off
> intersect_pct <- st_intersection(maricopa_tracts10, maricopa_blocks00)
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they
are planar
Warning message:
attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries 
> dim(intersect_pct)
[1] 74441    31
```

Just to show you how slow it is, here's the first 100 features only with spherical off and on:

```
> sf_use_s2(FALSE)
> system.time(intersect_pct <- st_intersection(maricopa_tracts10, maricopa_blocks00[1:100,]))
although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they
are planar
   user  system elapsed 
  0.115   0.004   0.120 

> sf_use_s2(TRUE)
Spherical geometry (s2) switched on
> system.time(intersect_pct <- st_intersection(maricopa_tracts10, maricopa_blocks00[1:100,]))
   user  system elapsed 
 22.781   0.167  22.951
```

At this rate the spherical intersection will take three hours for the full data set, or about a minute with planar geometry.

Does it matter? Depends on a lot of aspects of your geography, including possible legal definitions of straight lines in this jurisdiction - are they straight lines in planar lat-long, or great circles in spherical lat-long, or straight lines in some legal projected coordinate system (in which case transform to that and work in planar coordinates)?

But I think the validity error you are getting is related to the way spherical geometry sometimes works, but I don't have three hours to wait to find out...